# How do i build apache Tez on hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: apache, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, hadoop2

I am new to Apache Tez and Maven, I tried to install Apache Tez on my system.  I used the following link to install ,

http://tez.apache.org/install.html

In that pom.xml present in the apache tez i have only changed hadoop and protobuf version equal to my environment which are following,

hadoop 2.2.0
libprotoc-2.4.1,
Tez-0.5.0
maven 3.0.5
java -1.7.0_65

While doing

“ mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true “

i got the following error,

```
   Error :
    [ERROR] /home/karthick/work/apache-tez-0.5.0-src/tez-plugins/tez-yarn-timeline-history/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/dag/history/logging/ats/ATSHistoryLoggingService.java:[195,9] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol:   class TimelinePutError
    [ERROR] location: class org.apache.tez.dag.history.logging.ats.ATSHistoryLoggingService
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :tez-yarn-timeline-history
```

I have gone through that file  ATSHistoryLoggingService.java present in the apache tez, but i  couldn't understand what was  happening there. I dont know how to clear History logging Service.So I have tried again as newly. That time also i got the same error. I dont know how to proceed my installation process.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BUILDING.txt file at the top of the source tree. It has a pointer for "Building against a specific version of hadoop". You are missing a "-P!hadoop24" in your maven command. Also, I believe you need protobuf-2.5.0.